# Is there a way to programatically detach the built in media player from dbus?

Tags: multimedia, default-programs, dbus

The use case is:
I want to programatically control vlc or some other media player via DBus from python as a screenlet.  So in order for the other media player to register with DBus, I need to "unhook" banshee in a clean way.

I'm hoping for something more graceful than `killall banshee`.

An alternate solution could include forcing banshee not to launch on boot, so it doesn't register with DBus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is nothing ungraceful in `killall banshee`. `Kill` just happens to be the name of the signal passing application. You could of cause create an alias for kill with a more graceful name :-)

Apart from that, you really don't have to do that. Just send the play/pause/next/etc directly via dbus:
e.g.

> dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause

This does not interfere with any other player. (Assuming you have a vlc version that implements mpris2 (2.0) and you have started vlc with dbus enabled configuration).

Comment: Upvote for knowing that VLC can use a non-standard namespace via dbus.  I'm leaving it open in case someone addresses the detaching from dbus issue though.

Comment: I don't think that this is non-standard. You can control banshee for example simply by replacing vlc with banshee in the command above.

Comment: oops my bad...I read something on the VLC wiki that isn't accurate with the latest MPRIS DBus Spec.